# Combining Machine learning and Operations research on a scheduling problem

Tags: reference-request, scheduling, applications, machine-learning

I am wondering if there is any attempts of combining OR and ML in the following way. Priority-based rules are widely used in Resource Constrained Project Scheduling Problems. 
Is there a way to train a ML model to choose which priority rule to use? This may be done in advance depending on the structure of the input data or even while scheduling (i.e first using a priority rule then make a partial schedule using it then changing the priority rule etc.)

If it's the case, could you provide a link to papers and, if possible, a brief description of the idea behind (I am not familiar with ML at all)

Comment: I have seen this; learning which priority rule to use and learning "new" priority rule, see eg https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10951-006-5591-8 (I have no time to answer now, but google "learning priority rule" helps)